# Swapping values in assignemnt

Tags: python, computer-science

I'm a newbie taking Udacity's Intro to Computer Science course. We had a fairly simple question on our quiz about swapping values and I don't quite understand it. Here is the question:

Which of the following sequence of statements leaves the value of variable X the same as it was before the statements. Assume that both a and x refer to the integer values before this code.

Why is this true?

```
a,x = x,a
a,x = x,a
```

For example if I have:

```
a,x = 4,5
```

then
a = 4 and x = 5

For the second part:

```
a,x = 5, 4
```

then a = 5 and x = 4
So x is not equal to what it was before. Can someone explain why this is true?

Comment: Also, for both statements, you should do `a, x = x, a`, not replacing `x` and `a` with random integers you choose.

Comment: None of the statements have any "truth" to them. They're all assignments.

Comment: Because it's swapping twice.

Comment: You might find https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go interesting from 34:00 (actually, probably the whole presentation) from one of the python core developers. He explains why this feature was developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply swapping, then swapping again.

```
>>> a = 2
>>> x = 1
>>> a,x = x,a # We swapped them, so a = 1 and x = 2 now
              # During evaluation, this statement will be equivalent to "a,x = 1,2"
>>> a,x = x,a # And now we swap them again, so they're back to their original values
              # During evaluation, this statement will be equivalent to "a,x = 2,1"
>>> a
2
>>> x
1
```

What it seems you're missing is that the values change in the middle. You can't go through at the beginning and replace all occurrences of `x` and `a` with 4 and 5 in your example because `x` and `a` change in the middle of the operation.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the way Python's so-called unpacking assignments_ work. In essence the interpreter creates a list of destinations from the left-hand side and a list of values from the right-hand side of the assignment statement, then assigns the values to the destinations.

So in

```
a, b = 4, 5
```

you are assigning 4 to `a` and 5 to `b`. Then

```
a, b = b, a
```

assigns 5 (the current value of `b`) to `a` and 4 (the current value of `a`) to `b`.

Repeating the last statement therefore switches the values back to the original variables.